# Replace specified elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array defined by `A = np.zeros((4, 4, 4))`. Now suppose I want to set the elements `A[0, 2, 3], A[1, 1, 2], A[2, 1, 0], A[3, 0, 3]` to 1. Is there a way to do it in one line of code?

Edit: I tried `A[[0, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0], [3, 0, 3]] = 1` but this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well of course you can do simply this:

```
A[0, 2, 3], A[1, 1, 2], A[2, 1, 0], A[3, 0, 3] = 1,1,1,1
```

But I assume you are looking for advanced indexing?

```
A[[0,1,2,3],[2,1,1,0],[3,2,0,3]] = 1
```

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about the second approach, but couldn't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `A[0, 2, 3] = A[1, 1, 2] = A[2, 1, 0] = A[3, 0, 3] = 1`.